# Determine the difference between two fitted polinomials

Tags: matlab, octave, matlab-figure

First, I want to thank everybody who'll spend his time to work on my
problem.

I have two sets of data (X,Y,Z) which are almost the same, but with little differences. I have already fitted 'Poly22' surfaces to each of them. Now I would like to determine the difference between the two polynomials.

I have these values for each polynomial:

First set of data:
Linear model Poly22:

```
 SurfaceSzept26_2nd(x,y) = p00 + p10*x + p01*y + p20*x^2 + p11*x*y + p02*y^2

 Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
   p00 =       21.72  (17.28, 26.16)
   p10 =        58.6  (8.128, 109.1)
   p01 =       57.52  (7.158, 107.9)
   p20 =      -4.133  (-327.9, 319.6)
   p11 =      -2.464  (-678.4, 673.5)
   p02 =       4.744  (-349.1, 358.6)
```

2nd:

Linear model Poly22:

```
 SurfaceOkt30_2nd(x,y) = p00 + p10*x + p01*y + p20*x^2 + p11*x*y + p02*y^2

 Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
   p00 =       22.53  (18.2, 26.86)
   p10 =       61.86  (12.43, 111.3)
   p01 =       62.25  (12.93, 111.6)
   p20 =          -9  (-385.3, 367.3)
   p11 =     -0.5245  (-780.3, 779.3)
   p02 =       11.31  (-393.5, 416.2)
```

I know that the coefficients of the difference polynomial will be p(1st)-p(2nd). The task is to plot the difference surface in 3D. Could someone help me please? :)

Thanks all, have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might misunderstand your question, but I think you just mean to do this:

```
p00_3 =  21.72  -   22.53; %  = -0.81
p10_3 =   58.6  -   61.86; %  = -3.26
p01_3 =  57.52  -   62.25; %  = -4.73
p20_3 = -4.133  -      -9; %  =  4.867
p11_3 = -2.464  - -0.5245; %  = -1.9395
p02_3 =  4.744  -   11.31; %  = -6.566

[x,y] = meshgrid(-10:0.1:10);

surf(x,...
     y,...
     p00 + p10*x + p01*y + p20*x.^2 + p11.*x.*y + p02*y.^2,...
     'edgecolor', 'none')
```

Comment: helo! thanks for answer! i think this will be the solution, but one more question is not answered to me :\ at meshgrid function, which set of data should i use? may i have to make mean of them?Because i have x,y,z for set of data of September, and i have another set of data for October. thank you! :)

Comment: So the surfaces are : SurfaceSzept26_2nd(x1,y1) and SurfaceOkt30_2nd(x2,y2)